# System crashes after ext3_block_to_path

Tags: ext3

I have some soft which runs by cron. But once per day system crashes and only reboot helps.
This is the latest log (/var/log/syslog) before crashing:

```
Jul 31 05:00:01 T217 /USR/SBIN/CRON[22629]: (root) CMD (/root/TorrentStealer/cron.sh)
Jul 31 05:01:32 T217 /USR/SBIN/CRON[20743]: (CRON) error (grandchild #20745 failed with exit status 127)
Jul 31 05:04:17 T217 kernel: [30414.252246] EXT3-fs warning (device sda1): ext3_block_to_path: block < 0
Jul 31 05:04:17 T217 kernel: [30414.252246] EXT3-fs warning (device sda1): ext3_block_to_path: block < 0
```

And this is the latest log in /var/log/messages

```
Jul 31 05:04:17 T217 kernel: [30414.252246] EXT3-fs warning (device sda1): ext3_block_to_path: block < 0
Jul 31 05:04:17 T217 kernel: [30414.252246] EXT3-fs warning (device sda1): ext3_block_to_path: block < 0
```

So what does it mean?
This is uname -a:

```
Linux T217 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 12 03:40:32 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This issue started ~month ago. The soft running by cron is something like torrent client.

Comment: fsck it for the very beginning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @poige and @Pawel said, you most likely have a corrupted filesystem and you need to somehow fix it.

**HOWEVER**, if you have anything important stored on your disk, DO NOT just blindly run fsck. Before proceeding make sure you have decent backups *and* copy all the data from your disk to a brand new hard drive.

Such errors causing freezes do not just appear out of the blue; it might very well be your HD is dying and fsck would make more harm than good.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities:

1. You have corrupted filesystem. Unmount it and run fsck on it.
2. You have hit a bug in ext3.

Of the two the first is much more probable.